# complex java-script manipulation, array object sorting for new object

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects which i need to reshape for one other work. need some manipulation which will convert by one function. I have created plunker https://jsbin.com/himawakaju/edit?html,js,console,output

Main factors are Month, Country and its "AC" value.

```
var actual = [
 {"country":"UK","month":"JAN","SR":"John P","AC":"24","PR":"2","TR":1240},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"JAN","SR":"Brad    P","AC":"64","PR":"12","TR":1700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"JAN","SR":"Gim P","AC":"21","PR":"5","TR":900},

 {"country":"UK","month":"FEB","SR":"John P","AC":"14","PR":"4","TR":540},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"FEB","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":1700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"FEB","SR":"Gim P","AC":"22","PR":"3","TR":600},

 {"country":"UK","month":"MAR","SR":"John P","AC":"56","PR":"2","TR":1440},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"MAR","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"MAR","SR":"Gim P","AC":"51","PR":"5","TR":200}
 ];

var expect = [
{month:"JAN",val: {"UK":"24","AUSTRIA":"64","ITALY":"21"}},
{month:"FEB",val: {"UK":"14","AUSTRIA":"24","ITALY":"22"}},
{month:"MAR",val: {"UK":"56","AUSTRIA":"24","ITALY":"51"}}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var actual = [{
    "country": "UK",
        "month": "JAN",
        "SR": "John P",
        "AC": "24",
        "PR": "2",
        "TR": 1240
}, {
    "country": "AUSTRIA",
        "month": "JAN",
        "SR": "Brad    P",
        "AC": "64",
        "PR": "12",
        "TR": 1700
}, {
    "country": "ITALY",
        "month": "JAN",
        "SR": "Gim P",
        "AC": "21",
        "PR": "5",
        "TR": 900
},

{
    "country": "UK",
        "month": "FEB",
        "SR": "John P",
        "AC": "14",
        "PR": "4",
        "TR": 540
}, {
    "country": "AUSTRIA",
        "month": "FEB",
        "SR": "Brad P",
        "AC": "24",
        "PR": "12",
        "TR": 1700
}, {
    "country": "ITALY",
        "month": "FEB",
        "SR": "Gim P",
        "AC": "22",
        "PR": "3",
        "TR": 600
},

{
    "country": "UK",
        "month": "MAR",
        "SR": "John P",
        "AC": "56",
        "PR": "2",
        "TR": 1440
}, {
    "country": "AUSTRIA",
        "month": "MAR",
        "SR": "Brad P",
        "AC": "24",
        "PR": "12",
        "TR": 700
}, {
    "country": "ITALY",
        "month": "MAR",
        "SR": "Gim P",
        "AC": "51",
        "PR": "5",
        "TR": 200
}];
var monthsArray = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

function converter(actual) {
    var desiredArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < monthsArray.length; ++i) {
        debugger
        var obj = {};
        var innerObj = {};
        var month = '';
        for (var j = 0; j < actual.length; ++j) {
            if (monthsArray[i] == actual[j].month.toLowerCase()) {
                month = actual[j].month;
                innerObj[actual[j].country] = actual[j].AC;

            }
        }
        if (month.length > 0) {
            obj.month = month;
            obj.val = innerObj;
            desiredArr.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return desiredArr;
}
alert(JSON.stringify(converter(actual)));
```